# If a die is thrown $5$ times, what are the odds of getting a $5$ AT LEAST $3$ times

Tags: probability, dice

The probability of getting a $5$ three times is $0.03215$ but as we are looking for a $5$ to be rolled *at least* $3$ times, does that mean we add up the probabilities for getting a $5$ four and five times as well?

Comment: dice is plural :(

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: Yes, to find the probability of obtaining at least three fives, you have to add the probabilities of obtaining exactly three fives, exactly four fives, and exactly five fives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is the number of 5s, then $X\sim B\left(5,\frac{1}{6}\right)$. The probability of getting at least 3 fives is $$\mathbb P(X=3)+\mathbb P(X=4)+\mathbb P(X=5)$$
meaning that you have to sum the probabilities for getting 3, 4 and 5 fives.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a graph representation of your problem

The result is the sum of the 3 yellow bars (the latest 2 are very low...but they exist)

[image]

Same solution if you calculate 1 minus the burgundy bars